# main() method in a spring mvc application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, program-entry-point

My understanding of a basic Java application is that every application should have a main() method but when I wrote a Spring MVC application (not Spring Boot), I don't think there was ever a main() method that I wrote. Isn't it mandatory? What am I missing here? Or is this implemented in Spring somewhere internally? If yes, where is the main defined?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spring MVC is just a Servlet based framework which can only be run inside Servlet container like Tomcat or Webligic. The main method is deep in Servlet container that when you start will go and load war file into Java VM and delegate HTTP calls made to it to the appropriate Servlet that in turn will delegate to your Spring controller. For example when you run Tomcat startup.bat or startup.sh scripts they eventually will run Java main method.

Answer (score 2):

SpringMVC applications are typically run within an application server, for example Tomcat, so there is no main method like a traditional java program.  SpringMVC has a servlet that is loaded by the application server and starts the webapp.